# Haskell couldn't match expected type with actual type

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to use frequency analysis to decipher a code.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.Function
import qualified Data.Map as DMap

codedMsg    = "V'Z GELVAT GB GRNPU GUR PNIRZRA GB CYNL FPENOOYR. VG'F HCUVYY JBEX. GUR BAYL JBEQ GURL XABJ VF 'HAU', NAQ GURL QBA'G XABJ UBJ GB FCRYY VG."

mostFreqLtr = ["E", "T", "A", "O", "I", "N", "S", "H", "R", "D", "L", "C", "U", "M", "W", "F", "G", "Y", "P", "B", "V", "K", "X", "J", "Q", "Z"]

--weed out non alphabetical characters from the list
alphaSort lst
    | null lst              = []
    | isAlpha (head lst)    = (head lst) : alphaSort (tail lst)
    | otherwise             = alphaSort (tail lst)

--sort the list by characters
msgSort []  = []
msgSort lst = sortBy (compare `on` ord) lst

--group each character into it's own list
grp []  = []
grp lst = group lst

--sort the list into most frequent character first
lSort []    = []
lSort lst   = reverse (sortBy (compare `on` length) lst)

--change the list into one instance of each character
oneChar []  = []
oneChar lst = take 1 (head lst) : oneChar (tail lst)

--Pairing letters and creating a map of tuples containing frequency related characters
msg     = zip (oneChar $ lSort $ grp $ msgSort $ alphaSort $ map toUpper $ codedMsg) mostFreqLtr
msg2    = DMap.fromList msg

--replace coded list with analyzed list
replaceChars lst
    | null lst              = []
    | isAlpha (head lst)    = DMap.lookup (head lst) msg2 : replaceChars (tail lst)
    | otherwise             = (head lst) : replaceChars (tail lst)

result = replaceChars codedMsg
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
    Expected type: DMap.Map Char a0
      Actual type: DMap.Map [Char] [Char]
    In the second argument of `DMap.lookup', namely `msg2'
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely
      `DMap.lookup (head lst) msg2'
```

Answer (score 3):

Write type signatures on all your top-level functions. Then you will find that

```
oneChar :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

while, from the use, I surmise you intended

```
oneChar :: [[Char]] -> [Char]
```

Instead of `take 1`, you should have used `head`, or you should've `concat`ed the result to obtain a list of `Char`s.

As is, the map `msg2` that you construct has `[Char]` as keys, but you try to use it as if it had `Char`s as keys.

Answer (score 3):

hmm - I sat down and thought a bit about your code

- please use type signatures it helps a lot thinking about your code - and the compiler can optimize too
- give names that are a bit more meaningful

  - `mostFreqLtr` -> `freqTable_EN` (it makes clear you're deciphering English text)
  - `alphaSort` -> `filterAlpha` (it is misleading as you're filtering non letter elements and not sorting anything
  - `msgSort` -> `sort` (as it is the same i think)
- use pattern matching rather than `head` and `tail`
  i.e. lst ... head lst ... tail lst -> `lst@(c:cs)`

  - lst then is referrable as itself and `c` is its head and `cs` its tails (single elements are often referred as single letters, lists as their quasiplurals with appended *s*

### Code:

```
import Prelude hiding (lookup)
import Data.Char ( isAlpha
                 , toUpper)
import Data.List ( group
                 , sort
                 , sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Map ( fromList
                , lookup
                , Map)
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)
```

only import necessary bits of code

```
codedMsg :: String
codedMsg    = "V'Z GELVAT GB GRNPU GUR PNIRZRA GB CYNL FPENOOYR." ++ 
              "VG'F HCUVYY JBEX. GUR BAYL JBEQ GURL XABJ VF 'HAU'," ++
              "NAQ GURL QBA'G XABJ UBJ GB FCRYY VG."

freqTable_EN :: [Char]
freqTable_EN = ['E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'I', 'N', 'S', 'H', 'R'] ++
               ['D', 'L', 'C', 'U', 'M', 'W', 'F', 'G', 'Y'] ++
               ['P', 'B', 'V', 'K', 'X', 'J', 'Q', 'Z']
```

do not use too long lines - it makes code less readable, the last name `freqTable_EN` is quite unusual but in this case I feel free to deviate from standard as it is better readable. I also use `[Char]` instead of `String` (which is equivalent) to make it more clear that it is a table of letters.

```
-- weed out non alphabetical characters from the list
filterAlpha :: String -> String
filterAlpha = filter isAlpha

-- sort a list by length
sortByLength :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortByLength = sortBy (compare `on` length)

-- sort the list into most frequent character first
sortByFreq :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortByFreq = reverse . sortByLength
```

such comments are not necessary with good function names

```
-- change the list into one instance of each character
reduceGroups :: [[a]] -> [a]
reduceGroups lst = map head lst
```

you can also leave the `lst` thing the compiler is smart enough to get all information from the type signature so the last line could also be `reduceGroups = map head`

```
-- Pairing coded message with frequency table
pairs :: [(Char, Char)]
pairs = nonAlphaPairs ++ zip freqSortedMsg freqTable_EN
  where cleanedMsg    = (filterAlpha . map toUpper) codedMsg
        freqSortedMsg = (reduceGroups . sortByFreq . group . sort) cleanedMsg
        nonAlphaPairs = map (\x ->(x,x)) $ filter (not . isAlpha) codedMsg
```

`(\x -> (x,x))` is a lambda expression it simply transforms a single character in a pair as they're deciphered by themselves

```
-- and creating a map for decryption
cipher :: Map Char Char
cipher = fromList pairs

-- replace encoded text by our cipher
decipher :: String -> String
decipher = mapMaybe (uplook cipher)
         where uplook = flip lookup

result :: String
result = decipher codedMsg

main :: IO ()
main = print result
```

the last line makes your result printed - as we want to read the message ;-)
Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

PS.: I really like your coded message - though not even one letter is found by frequency analysis. I just guessed your ciphering algorithm. (`g?` for vim users),
I think you have to use a longer text.

Comment: i have to correct myself there is one letter caught by frequency analysis - it's `V`; in the longer text I found at the wikipedia article on frequency analysis there are C,E,I,W,X found correctly.